# How to switch website when importing products from a CSV file?

Tags: product, import

I have created a new store for wholesale customers. For wholesale customers, I want to set a different price. We can set it by backend manually, when adding a new product by switching website. But I have lots of products. By doing manually, it takes too much time to finish.

How to switch website when importing product from CSV? I have tried with _product_websites, store_id, websites. etc., keyword with the corresponding wholesale id. It changes main store price too.

Have any idea?

Comment: What does importing products have to do with switching websites? You have one installation with different stores and websites I guess? Per website or shop you can set different prices.

Comment: yeah. in single magento installation, i have 2 websites, each have one store. system->cofiguration->catalog-> price here i have set catalog price scope as website.

Comment: You could take a look at catalog price rules, but I'm afraid that they don't fit your needs. Another option is to look for a module to manage product prices.

Comment: so can't we set different price to wholesale website by csv file?

Comment: I don't know how, I think you need to look at other methods.

Comment: @rxt fixed yar! thank you so much for your reply. In store field, i have replaced default "admin" by "wholesale" . Now the above issue was fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*For Short answer*, you can refer the comments under question.

*For detail referrence*

First setting price for wholesale to anyone product manually.

Goto **catalog->manage products ->enter into anyone product.** 
There, switch website into wholesale.

[image]

Here **uncheck the use default value checkbox**. Then enter wholesale price and hit save button.

Now This product having different price in main store and wholesale store

Then Export this product in **system->import/export->Data flow-Profiles ->export all products**. Then in profile wizard tab select your wholesale website in store

[image]

Then enter that sku in sku field

[image]

Then hit save and continue button. And run export. Then you can see that export file in **var/export** folder. In this excel file, you can see the difference for wholesale. In store field, you have to enter your wholesale website code.

Now make these changes in your new file. And import it again. It will be work. Cheers!

**Note:** Its only for editing products. Not for adding new products

For model CSV please look at [here](http://chillydraji.wordpress.com/2014/02/15/how-to-switch-website-when-import-products-by-csv/)